# Using RubyMine to Debug Fastlane

Tags: rubymine, fastlane

I'm looking for a working configuration for debugging Fastlane (Ruby) scripts in RubyMine.

A normal command-line invocation of fastlane looks like:

```
bundle exec fastlane ios build_my_project
```

where the code is contained in a ruby file in `fastlane/Fastfile`.

Is it possible to debug these scripts like regular ruby scripts?

### Bundle in rbenv - Ruby 2.6.3

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
[ -n "$RBENV_DEBUG" ] && set -x

program="${0##*/}"
if [ "$program" = "ruby" ]; then
  for arg; do
    case "$arg" in
    -e* | -- ) break ;;
    */* )
      if [ -f "$arg" ]; then
        export RBENV_DIR="${arg%/*}"
        break
      fi
      ;;
    esac
  done
fi

export RBENV_ROOT="/Users/palmerc/.rbenv"
exec "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec/rbenv" exec "$program" "$@"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should be quite possible. In a terminal do below

```sh
$ which bundle
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/bundle
```

In case you are using `rbenv` for your `ruby` environment use below to get the `bundle` path

```sh
$ rbenv which bundle
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/bundle
```

Now this is a ruby file only. So only thing you need to do now is build a debug configuration with this file as the starting point

and then you can add rest of the command as script arguments

[image: Debug Config]

Comment: What is the output of `cat /Users/palmerc/.rbenv/shims/bundle`?

Comment: Run `rbenv which bundle` and then use that path for debugging